# Getting Error for using document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, html

THE CODE

```
const copy = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-me');

copy.addEventListener('copy', function(){
    console.log('OI! My content has copyright!');
    alert(' OI! My content has copyright! ');
});
```

**THE ERROR**
Uncaught TypeError: copy.addEventListener is not a function
at sandbox.js:3

**NO ERROR CODE**

```
const copy = document.querySelector('.copy-me');

copy.addEventListener('copy', function(){
    console.log('OI! My content has copyright!');
    alert(' OI! My content has copyright! ');
});
```

*I want to use multiple class that is why i want* **".querySelectorAll"**

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is obvious since you are accessing the collection. Method `forEach()` will help you as one of many options.

The collection needs to define the current item. Like this:

```
copy.forEach(function(copy_current) {
  copy_current.addEventListener('copy', function(){
  ...
```

Use this complete code:

```
const copy = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-me');

copy.forEach(function(copy_current) {
  copy_current.addEventListener('copy', function(){
    console.log('OI! My content has copyright!');
    alert(' OI! My content has copyright! ');
  });
});
```